# how do i redirect to home page(root )when user signed out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get devise working on my simple rails app where;

1.I'd like when user_signed out it will redirect to home page(root).!

2.when the user create his/her own products, when go to products.index it will show all the products that users have created, and when signed in as a specific user, the person will see their own created products on the user dashboard.(at the moment the added products will automatically added to the products index page)

many thanks!

```
<header class="navbar">



  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> Products <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Create a product",new_product_path %>
             </li>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "View all the products", products_path%></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Profile <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <%= link_to "My dashboard", profile_path %>
          <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</header>
```

```
<h2>Log in</h2>


<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class='signup_create_product'>
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: false,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" } %>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: false,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end


  def create

     @product = Product.new(product_params)
     @product.user = current_user

    if @product.save
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end



  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :description)
  end
end
```

user show page

```
 <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the official devise guide to redirection after sign out:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out

In short, add this to your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  ...
  private

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1:

Check @Mark answer

Regarding question 2:

Assuming you have the relationship:

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

```
# app/models/product.rb

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the `user#show` implementation add

```
# app/controller/users_controller.rb

def show
  ...
  @products = current_user.products
  ...
end
```

Now in the `users/show` view you can loop `@products` for the user's products.

```
<h1>User products</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
  </tr>

  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
      <td><%= product.description %></td>
      <td><%= product.condition %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: no problem! thank you very much! in the product.index page i'd like to to show all the products that users have created and in the specific user dashboard(user/show);I'd like to show the products that the specific user has created to be shown on his/her own dashboard.

Comment: @developing I edited my answer, let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: hi @alexalth thank you ! is it something like this on user/show? 
```
<% if @user == current_user %>



<h1><%= @product.each do |product|  %></h1>
 <h1>  <%= @product.product_name  %></h1>
      <p><%= @product.description %> <%= @product.condition %></p>

 <% end %>
 <% end %>
``` but it's not appearing on the dashboard, is there any other file i can provided for you? thx!

Comment: @developing Inside the loop remove the @ so refer to each product as `product` not `@product`. Only refer to the collection `@products` with @, e.g. `@products.each do |product|`

Comment: yes,I've changed and it still not working not showing on the dashboard.

Comment: @developing check out the new edit, I put a sample code for the view. Let me know.

Comment: hi @alexalth thank you very much! the view/show helps a lot but after i did this in the user/show method it works now!  

    @ products = current_user.products

Comment: @developing cool, you're welcome. I'll edit with this change.